# Are Indexes needed in Azure Sql Data Warehouse table to boost performance on multi table join query

Tags: sql-server, azure, indexing, data-warehouse

My understanding in an Azure SQL Data Warehouse table, each column is indexed in a column store table (maybe I'm wrong).  If that is the case, why is there ability to create additional indexes (Create Index statement).  I was thinking maybe due to composite index (Multiple field indexes).

But in a query with a single field join, after creating an index on that field, the performance got much better.

Is there some general rule to go by when creating indexes in Azure Sql Data Warehouse?

Answer (score 0):

Generally we should create index on the column which are more used in any query. Index are also a burden on a database because Index take some space in the disk.  Creating Index on all the column of a table is not a good idea. we should make Index on the basis of query.

Besides index we can use Partition or table space to boost query performance.

Comment: I would agree with you in normal SQL server.  In a SQL Data Warehouse, I think it works differently. I'm trying to find Best Practices on index creation for PDW.